# SQS Billing when triggering lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

SQS [pricing page](https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/pricing/) mentioned

> Every Amazon SQS action counts as a request

SQS pricing strategy has some pricing buckets, like *First 1 Million Requests/Month is Free*, *From 1 Million to 100 Billion Requests/Month for Standard Queue is $0.40*, etc.

As per [AWS doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html), to trigger lambda from SQS, three SQS actions are required as given below.

1. `sqs:ReceiveMessage`
2. `sqs:DeleteMessage` and
3. `sqs:GetQueueAttributes`.

My questions are

1. For every lambda invocation (triggering) do all these three actions are execute?
2. If yes, do all these actions are treated as a request?

In that case, every trigger for each 64KB payload chunk consumes 3 requests. If this understanding is wrong then what is the request count calculation for every trigger execution?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are worried about something that costs 40c per million actions? You'll probably find that the majority of your expenses lie elsewhere.

Comment: I am actually comparing SQS-lambda integration costing with EventBridge-lambda integration. For that, I am interested in the actual calculation. EventBridge is always at the higher-end though, but to put some data point I would like to know above detal. Is there any other hidden expense(s) I am missing?

Comment: There are different products. EventBridge is a streaming platform for events, you can consider it is as a topic source. Yes using the SQS+Lambda you will get similar functionality, but they may be different limits or constraints